# Check in Wordpress if the oppened post belong to a category

Tags: wordpress

I want to check if my oppened post belong to one of my category that i've displayed also on post page. If the post  belongs to one of my category then i want to add a style for the title of category(color:red;). So, i have created the next code:

```js
 <?php
$arg = array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_per_page' => 12,
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
);
$categories = get_categories($arg);
$post_id = get_the_ID();

?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category); ?>" class="test">
        <span class="name"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php $x =$category->term_id  ?>
    
}
 ?>
<?php endforeach; // $categories as $category ?>
```

i got the post ID and the category ID but i can't manage to get what i want. I supose that probably i should use `in_category`. Who knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried <?php has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post ) ?>

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

1. Create a CSS class in your main CSS file that has the style you want

   ```
   .red {
   color: red;
   }
   ```
2. Adjust your for loop to include a variable that contains the ID or an array of IDs for the categories you want to check against.  As well the current category ID. Also, add a variable with an empty string that we can use to add as a class to your span later on.

   ```
   $current_cat_id = $category->term_id;
   $check_cat_id = array(122,178); // Add the ID or IDs of the categories you want to check against
   $red_class = ''; // An empty string var we'll use for the span class below
   ```
3. Then check the current post term ID against the array of term IDs.  If it exists in the array, you change the class variable to your CSS class name.

   ```
   /* Check to see if the current cat ID matches to the one you want to check for */

     if (in_array($current_cat_id, $check_cat_id)) {

       // Put the class name of the CSS class you create as this string

       $red_class = 'red'; 

     }
   ```
4. Lastly, echo the class variable on your span.  If the IF statement is true, it will echo your class name, if it's not, it will not add that class to the span.

   ```
   <span class="name <?php echo $red_class; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
   ```

Here is the whole thing together:

```
    <?php
    $arg = array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_per_page' => 12,
    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
    );

    $categories = get_categories($arg);
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    ?>

    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>

     $current_cat_id = $category->term_id;
     $check_cat_id = array(122); // Add the ID or IDs of the categories you want to check against
     $red_class = ''; // An empty string var we'll use for the span class below

/* Check to see if the current cat ID matches to the one you want to check for */

     if (in_array($current_cat_id, $check_cat_id)) {

        // Put the class name of the CSS class you create as this string

        $red_class = 'red'; 
     }

    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category); ?>" class="test">

    /* Echo the red_class var in the span class so that if it's matched it will have the class you assign */

    <span class="name <?php echo $red_class; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
    </a>


   }
   ?>
   <?php endforeach; // $categories as $category ?>
```